# Problems retrieving content controls with Open XML sdk

Tags: ms-office, sharepoint-2013, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am developing a solution that will generate word-documents. The word-documents are generated on the basis of a template document which has defined content controls. Everything was working good for me when I had only one content control in my template, but after expanding the template document with more content controls, I am getting exceptions. It seems like I am not finding the content controls.

This is my method:

```
private void CreateReport(File file)

    {
        var byteArray = file.OpenBinary();
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            mem.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            try
            {
                using (var wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, true))
                {
                    var mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;

                    var firstName = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where
                        (r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "FirstName").Single();
                    var t = firstName.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                    t.Text = _firstName;

                     var lastName = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where
                        (r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "LastName").Single();
                     var t2= lastName.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                     t2.Text = _lastName;

                    mainPart.Document.Save();
                    SaveFileToSp(mem);
                }

            }
            catch (FileFormatException)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the exception I get:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code. Innerexception: Null

Any tips for me on how I can write better method for finding controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that one (or more) of your calls to `Single()` is being called on a sequence that has more than one element. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb155325%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for `Single()` states (emphasis mine):

> Returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception if there is not **exactly one element** in the sequence.

In your code this can happen in one of two scenarios. The first is if you have more than one control with the same `Tag` value, for example you might have two controls in the document labelled "LastName" which would mean that this line

```
var lastName = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where
                    (r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "LastName")
```

would return two elements.

The second is if your content control has more than one `Text` element in it in which case this line

```
var t = firstName.Descendants<Text>();
```

would return multiple elements. For example if I create a control with the content "This *is* a test" I end up with XML which has 4 `Text` elements:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00086A5B" w:rsidRDefault="003515CB">
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rStyle w:val="PlaceholderText" />
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">This </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rStyle w:val="PlaceholderText" />
            <w:i />
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>is</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rStyle w:val="PlaceholderText" />
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidR="00E1178E">
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rStyle w:val="PlaceholderText" />
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>a test</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

How to get round the first issue depends on whether you wish to replace *all* of the matching `Tag` elements or just one particular one (such as the first or last).

If you want to replace just one you can change the call from `Single()` to `First()` or `Last()` for example but I guess you need to replace them all. In that case you need to loop around each matching element for each tag name you wish to replace.

Removing the call to `Single()` will return an `IEnumerable<SdtBlock>` which you can iterate around replacing each one:

```
IEnumerable<SdtBlock> firstNameFields = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where
    (r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "FirstName");

foreach (var firstName in firstNameFields)
{
    var t = firstName.Descendants<Text>().Single();
    t.Text = _firstName;
}
```

To get around the second problem is slightly more tricky. The *easiest* solution in my opinion is to remove all of the existing paragraphs from the content and then add a new one with the text you wish to output.

Breaking this out into a method probably makes sense as there's a lot of repeated code - something along these lines should do it:

```
private static void ReplaceTags(MainDocumentPart mainPart, string tagName, string tagValue)
{
    //grab all the tag fields
    IEnumerable<SdtBlock> tagFields = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where
        (r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == tagName);

    foreach (var field in tagFields)
    {
        //remove all paragraphs from the content block
        field.SdtContentBlock.RemoveAllChildren<Paragraph>();
        //create a new paragraph containing a run and a text element
        Paragraph newParagraph = new Paragraph();
        Run newRun = new Run();
        Text newText = new Text(tagValue);
        newRun.Append(newText);
        newParagraph.Append(newRun);
        //add the new paragraph to the content block
        field.SdtContentBlock.Append(newParagraph);
    }
}
```

Which can then be called from your code like so:

```
using (var wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, true))
{
    var mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;

    ReplaceTags(mainPart, "FirstName", _firstName);
    ReplaceTags(mainPart, "LastName", _lastName);

    mainPart.Document.Save();
    SaveFileToSp(mem);
}
```

Comment: Hi petelids. Thank you very much for the valuable input. I tried this, but get: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Sequence contains more than one element. Inner exception: null.

Comment: Sorry @Ilyas, I didn't think about there being more than one `Text` element. Please see my update...

Comment: Thank you, sir, thank you very much. If I had enough reputation I would give all your posts a point. I was struggling big time with this. Now I can get all tags except the the first. Do you know how to include the first one also?

Comment: Thanks @Ilyas - if the answer has helped then feel free to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). The first tag *should* work just like all of the others. Try checking the value of `tagFields` for the first tag to see if it's found - don't forget that your name search is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Single()` method is causing the exception.

When you got only one content control, `Single()` can get the only available element. But when you expand the content controls, your `Single()` method can cause `InvalidOperationException` as there are more than one element in the sequence. If this is the case, try to loop your code and take one element at a  time.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your very valuable tips. Do you got any samples on how to loop for content controls ?

Comment: You can simply loop on the descendants of SdtBlock, just like in your linq query - `mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>()`

Comment: Hi again. I am not sure I understand. Could you please tell how to specifically change this code to loop correctly ? :)


   var lastName = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where
                            (r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "LastName").Single();
                         var t2= lastName.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                         t2.Text = _lastName;