# Open XML word content controls

Tags: ms-word, openxml

Here is my code trying to get the content controls with the tag "company"

```
                using (WordprocessingDocument template = WordprocessingDocument.Open("d:/dev/ProposalTemplate1.dotx", true))
                {
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = template.MainDocumentPart;
                SdtBlock block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "TEST").Single();
                Text t = block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                t.Text = "COMPANY_NAME"; 
                }
```

I got the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" because of the query line but I don't know why...

This works well when I create a simple template with just one content controls but not when using a bigger word template

Any idea ?

**EDIT** 
I try doing it without `.Single()` but still not working

```
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = template.MainDocumentPart;
            var blocks = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "Company");
            foreach (SdtBlock block in blocks)
            {
                Text t = block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                t.Text = "COMPANY1";
            }
```

**EDIT 2** 
I change the Text.Single()
The problem is still there "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the `SdtBlock block = ...` line

```
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = template.MainDocumentPart;
            var blocks = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "Company");
            foreach (SdtBlock block in blocks)
            {
                var t = block.Descendants<Text>();
                foreach (Text text in t)
                {
                    text.Text = "COMPANY1";
                }
            }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems retrieving content controls with Open XML sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29010291/problems-retrieving-content-controls-with-open-xml-sdk)

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem :( I edited my question

Comment: You are still using `Single()` on the `Text` line - `Text t = block.Descendants<Text>().Single();`. There could be more than one.

Comment: Doesn't change :/ I edit my question again

Comment: By *the `SdtBlock block = ` line* do you mean the `var blocks =` line as there is no longer an `SdtBlock block = ` line?

Comment: please share answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all `SdtBlock` elements have child `Tag` elements. You are assuming one exists and attempting to access the `Val` property but are getting a null reference exception in doing so.

You can fix it by checking for null within the `Where` predicate:

```
var blocks = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where(r => 
    {
        var tag = r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>();
        return tag != null && tag.Val == "Company";
    });
```

As per the comments there is more information about the issues you originally had with using `Single` in my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29031850/3791802).

Comment: So, I got no more error but It doesn't find the tag... There is always no results with the query

Comment: Silly question but have you actually added the Tag property to the Control in the Word document?

Comment: Is it in the same case (the compare is case sensitive)?

Comment: first letter in uppercase, yes same case

Comment: Are you absolutely *sure* you've got a Tag? If you were getting a null reference exception before changing to the above and now you're not then `tag` must be null. If that's the case then your block possibly doesn't have a Tag at all (I say possibly as it's possible a different block doesn't have a tag).

Comment: I think so... I'll double check my word

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach( SdtBlock sdt in sdtList )
                    {
                        if( sdt.SdtProperties != null )
                        {
                            Tag tag = sdt.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>();

                            if( tag!= null )
                            {
                                if( tag.Val.Value == "Company" )
                                {
                                    if( sdt.InnerText != string.Empty )
                                    {
                                        //Do something
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Not working... Maybe it's about my word template and not the code

Answer (score 0):

Accepted solution returns no results on my query either. So i come up with this solution;

```
var doc = document.MainDocumentPart.Document;
List<Tag> sdtSubTable = doc.Body.Descendants<Tag>().Where(r =>
{
return r != null && r.Val.Value.Contains("Company");
}).ToList();
```