# Find Content Control by TagName in Word document in OpenXml

Tags: c#, openxml, contentcontrol

I am attempting to insert text in to a content control in my word document template using OpenXml. First I search the content control by its tag name and then adding paragraph element in the SdtBlock like below,

```
SdtBlock contentBlock = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>()
   .Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "AssessmentSection")
   .Single();
```

But when I execute this statement, I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error message. The template document already has another content control and I was able to find that control using the same above statement with only tagname as different. But after adding "AssessmentSection" content control in template and while running the program, I get "Object Reference..." error for "AssessmentSection" control and the program fails. I am sure the new content control tag name and title are unique with other content control.

Can someone please help me why this strange behaviour is occurring and how to fix it???

Comment: What is actually null? In your where clause you have `r.SdtProperties`, if `SdtProperties` is null for any element in your collection you will get a null reference. If that's a possibility, check for it: `r => r.SdtProperties != null && r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild...` You might also need to check if `GetFirstChild<Tag>()` actually returns something for all your elements. If it doesn't, you'll get null reference there too.

Comment: Have a look at my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532841/open-xml-word-content-controls/29539288#29539288) - does that help?

Answer (score -2):

you also could loop the documents ContentControls items and check their tags, like:

```
foreach (Word.ContentControl contentcontrol in wordDoc.ContentControls)
{
   if (contentcontrol.Tag != null)
   {
          ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Not a complete answer, but could be useful for other reasons than those in the OPs question. This looks like a snip from the sample code from Eric White's blog here: http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/iterating-through-all-content-controls-in-an-open-xml-wordprocessingml-document/ .